# Can I use ecmascript 6 in cocos2d JS?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, ecmascript-6, cocos2d-js

Does cocos2d js support latest standard for javascript? I would like to use it in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exaclty if cocos supports ES6, but I tried to push an array into another array by using ES6:

```
array1.push(...array2);
```

It seems to work. Nevertheless I don't think you will need ES6 for cocos2d-js, because it's a huge library, which provides you all the features you need.

Comment: ES 6 introduces many things (for example new syntax) that no library can provide.

Answer (score 2):

1. Cocos2d-js support **some** ES6 features but **not all** (Ex. Support: `let`, `const`, arrow function, `Array.prototype.find`, `Array.prototype.findIndex`. Not supported: default paramenter, `class`, etc).
2. You can also use ES6 and convert it to ES5 (using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)). I found [this](https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-js-es6-babel-gulp/29176) on Cocos2d-x forum, you can take a look.